# Как создать новую View

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Собираю программу в стороннем движке, который потом перекидывает архив в Xcode. Опыта работы с objC нет, так что заранее извиняюсь за возможную глупость написанного.
Проблема в том, что главный View, с которым предлагает работать движок, создан на основе EAGLView. И при попытке подгрузить и отобразить там контент с помощью некоторых сторонних фреймворков - вылезает ошибка, связанная с фреймбуфером.

```
extern UIView *g_glView; // это view движка
[theInterstitiel show:g_glView]; // ->> краш
```

Вероятно, его нужно отображать в простом View без OpenGL.
Если написать:

```
[theInterstitiel show:self.view];
```

То баннер загружается отлично, я слышу звуки, но не вижу самого баннера.
Можно ли программно добавить view, не имеющего отношения к EAGLView, и поднять его на самый верх?
Доступа к UIViewController.h и тп нет, все закрыто.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если вам просто нужно создать UIView программно и добавить, тогда попробуйте так:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 150, 200, 50)];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubView:view];
```

Comment: Спасибо! Понадобилось ещё дописать это, что бы вид появился выше основного:    UIWindow* promowindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    [promowindow addSubview: view];

Comment: Да это я забыл указать.(

Comment: какая то стремная практика добавлять view к keyWindow

Comment: Подскажите, как лучше добавить? Этот вид планируется использовать единожды всего пару секунд. Потом удаляю так: [view removeFromSuperview];